# Ubuntu's Desktop only has wallpaper but nothing after mounting /home

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I am a beginner to Ubuntu,I has been installed Ubuntu for a few days.Today it noticed me it doesn't has enough room,and then I execute the command.

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda6 /home
```

But unfortunately,when I restart my computer,I found that after I login with my username and password,I only can see my wallpaper in my desktop,and other things are disappeared. There are two additional messages:

1.I can login with the role of guest

2.I have ever backupd with the system's tool,and the backups are in the directory named deja-dup.But I don’t know how to use them ,they are all gpg files.

I am so nervous ,so come here to ask for help.Thank you very much.

The result of command `mount` as follows:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
overflow on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,size=1048576,mode=1777)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/112/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=lightdm)
```

Comment: Could you run the command `mount` and add the result to your question please?

Comment: I have added the result to my question.Maybe some of my operation may change something.

Comment: Where exactly is there not enough space? Have you tried deleting something? The `df -h` command might be more useful with space problems.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you manually mounted your `/dev/sda6` (whatever it is). But at shut down, it is unmounted and you'd have to manually mount again after restarting. You can make the mount permanent through `/etc/fstab`.

Assuming that your `/dev/sda6` is a partition of your hard drive and that it has an `ext4` filesystem on it, you can use these steps to permanently put your home directory on it. Make sure to also check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving.
I'm using the command line for all steps.

1. Find the UUID of `/dev/sda6`:

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```

Why UUID? In Ubuntu, it is now best practice to use the device's UUID instead of it's name, because the UUID is truly unique and won't change.

2. Make a backup copy of the file /etc/fstab:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.ori
   ```

You can compare the copy and the original to make sure you have a correct backup:

```
    sudo cmp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.ori # should show no output
```

3. Open `/etc/fstab` in an editor. I'll use `nano`. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (the letter, not the number) to save changes and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/fstab
   ```

Add the following line to the bottom. Replace [UUID] with the UUID of your device (copy the string with the dashes, but without the quotes).

```
    UUID=[UUID]    /media/home    ext4    defaults    0    2
```

Save and exit.
4. Create the mount point and then remount everything that is in `/etc/fstab`:

```
    sudo mkdir /media/home
    sudo mount -a
```

This will mount your `/dev/sda6` device on `/media/home`.
5. We'll now copy the contents of the current home directory to `/dev/sda6`. Using `rsync` with the `-avz` flags makes sure that metadata like file ownership and times are copied as well. The diff command checks if all files copied correctly, it should show difference in `.bash_history` only.

```
    sudo rsync -avz /home/ /media/home/
    sudo diff -r /home /media/home
```

6. Change the mount point of your `/dev/sda6` device to `/home` in `/etc/fstab` (open with `sudo nano`):

   ```
   UUID=[UUID]    /home    ext4    defaults    0    2
   ```
7. We'll now move the current home directory away and create a new, empty home directory. After remounting your `/dev/sda6` device is mounted on `/home` and also automatically mounted at boot. Everything in `/home` is now on your `/dev/sda6` device.

   ```
   sudo mv /home /old_home
   sudo mkdir /home
   sudo mount -a
   ```

After you have made sure everything is in place you can remove the old home with:

```
    sudo rm -rf /old_home
```

## Done!

Comment: Because when using numbered lists, you need to use 8 spaces!  (See my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/753000/revisions) **;-)** En welkom aan boord trouwens!