# How to use backup files in deja-dup when I can only operate in terminal

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Just because of one mistake,my desktop has desktop only with wallpaper.The good thing I have ever backupd with the system's tool,and the backups are in the directory named deja-dup.But I don’t know how to use them ,they are all gpg files.
So I want to ask the question how should I use them when I only can operate in terminal.I'm anxious,and Thank you for you to answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu's Desktop only has wallpaper but nothing after mounting /home](http://askubuntu.com/questions/752975/ubuntus-desktop-only-has-wallpaper-but-nothing-after-mounting-home)

Comment: I doubt this is going to work, before the space problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just type:
`man deja-dup`
in the terminal and read the manual of deja-dup.
what you need is probably:
`deja-dup --restore [FILES?]`
Between the bracket type the whole address of the Deja-dup file/s